# Where did the Gabare Jahangiri Dynasty assert authority?

Tags: political-history, islam, political-geography, central-asia

Where did the [Sunni Muslim dynasty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Sunni_Muslim_dynasties) assert authority?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jahangiris (1190-1520), a Tajik dynasty, were the original Sultans of [Swat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swat_(princely_state)).* They ruled in parts of modern Afghanistan and Pakistan.

From [The Glossary of the Tribes and Castes of the Punjab](https://books.google.com/books?id=1QmrSwFYe60C&pg=PA340&lpg=PA340&dq=Jahangiri%20dynasty&source=bl&ots=qMW57-kb8a&sig=YdxhKQSNoOWoCtBOatOzayayPu8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7ILnVIPJMseigwTX7IDwBA&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=Jahangiri%20dynasty&f=false):

> A dynasty of Sultans who, according to Raverty, once ruled from
>   [Nangrahar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nangarhar_Province) to the [Jhelum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jhelum_River) but, by the time the Kheshi Pathans overran
>   Swat, their sway did not extend far beyond the Indus on the east . . .
>   They claim descent from Alexander the Great. The Jahangiri also
>   appears to survive as a sept of the Gibari.

Sultan Awes, the last Sultan of Swat, was expelled from this territory along with his Tajik subjects. They settled near the source of the [Oxus River](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amu_Darya), where they ruled for several more generations "as far as the frontier of [Badakhshan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badakhshan)."

Wikipedia has little on this particular dynasty, but a few details may be found in this article on [Sikandar Butshikan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikandar_Butshikan):

> His cousins were ruling the area from [Kabul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabul) to [Sind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sind) ([Indus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indus)). They had
>   been ruling Kabul lagmant and [Swat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swat_(princely_state)) in 1190–1520, are known as
>   Jahangiri dynasty in history.

[When Babur invaded Bajaur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bajaur_Agency#Babur.27s_attack_on_Bajaur) in 1518, the defender was a Jahangirian Sultan.

---

* Okay, I don't know if they were the original, but they were older than [Babe Ruth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babe_Ruth).